# Why is $_SESSION not carrying data to separate PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a login page that sets a `$_SESSION['usertype']` when I log in. I have a separate PHP file that contains a menu that loads on the side. That file is loaded on every PHP file through

`<?php include('menu.php') ?>`

But when I check for `$_SESSION['usertype']` in menu.php, it is not set.

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just checking whether you're using [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you include the file which needs to access `$_SESSION['usertype']`?

Have a check through [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php).

Comment: So it should only be at the begining of menu.php, not the other file? Thanks!

Comment: @Eric you need to call `session_start()` either at the top of your main php file OR at top of menu.php i suggest put at the top of the initial file you load (which includes menu.php). This way your session is available to all of your PHP application

Answer (score 1):

Do you have session_start() at the top of menu.php or before the include of menu.php?

Comment: No, but would that start a new session, or continue the other one... or should I just have it at the top of menu.php, not the other file? Thanks!

Comment: it will only continue if there is one running, it's name is a bit misleading

Comment: It's tricky to explain, it will resume if there is a session. Safe to say: you _need_ to call session_start always before using the $_SESSION global.

Comment: I think documentation explains it well enough, and also has a "two page" example: "session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie." http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php